# With a lmer model, can I extract the fitted values of 'y' for the whole model

Tags: r, statistics, regression, lme4, mixed-models

I am a novice with R and this is a very basic question. I am using lmer to fit a mixed model to a data frame, as follows:

```r
model1=lmer(Mass~Season + Area + Month + (1|Season:Month), data=Transdata)
```

and then using `ggplot2` to plot the fitted data and various diagnostics. For example, for fitted values:

```r
ggplot(model1, aes(x = Season, y = Mass)) + geom_point()
```

gives me a plot of Mass per Season, shown separately for each of the 3 different areas and 4 different months. Is there a way in which I can get a single estimate of the mean Mass per Season integrated across the different Areas and Months (i.e. from the fixed effects), and e.g. the SEs for each estimate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to do this is

```r
library(emmeans)
emmeans(model1, ~ Season)
```

I think you could reparameterize/modify the formula so that the parameters corresponded to means per season (rather than the default, which is to fit an intercept corresponding to the first season and then parameterize the model in terms of differences between seasons), but using `emmeans` is easier.

Comment: Thanks, Ben. emmeans has given me what I was looking for:                                  
 Season    emmean    SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 2013-2014   5.53 0.115 Inf      5.31      5.76
 2014-2015   5.35 0.114 Inf      5.12      5.57
 2015-2016   5.13 0.113 Inf      4.91      5.36
 2016-2017   5.20 0.113 Inf      4.98      5.43
 2017-2018   5.18 0.113 Inf      4.96      5.40
 2018-2019   5.13 0.115 Inf      4.91      5.36

Results are averaged over the levels of: Area, Month 
Degrees-of-freedom method: asymptotic 
Confidence level used: 0.95

Comment: If this solved your problem, you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it ...

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way in which I can get a single estimate of the mean Mass per Season integrated across the different Areas and Months (i.e. from the fixed effects), and e.g. the SEs for each estimate?

If I have understood the question properly, surely just the output from `summary(model1)` will provide this. It will give a separate estimate for each level of Season, apart from the reference level, and each estimate is then the expected difference in `Mass` for each `Season` relative to the reference level, keeping the other fixed effects constant, which would seem to answer your question.

---

Edit: After re-reading the question, the title seems to ask a different question to the body. As for the title:

> With a lmer model, can I extract the fitted values of 'y' for the whole model

Yes, you can simply run

```
fitted(model1)
```

Comment: Thanks Robert. 
On your 1st suggestion, the intercept gives mean Mass for the first season (2013/14) just in one Area (6) and one month (Dec).  (Intercept + Season effect) will give equivalent estimates per Season rather than the mean Mass per Season integrating all areas and months.    
Running ‘fitted(model1)’ gives the fitted value of each data point i.e.:
 26       27       28 ...     
5.483981 5.483981 5.483981 ... 
 
+ several thousand entries.  
Is there a function in R that can generate from model1, the overall mean Mass per Season and confidence intervals?  Thanks again.